# Dragging in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I feel strange that I cannot find the actual dragging-handling code in Fabric.js's demo (for example, [this one)](http://fabricjs.com/controls-customization/), but the objects are already draggable "automatically", which is not my case. Here's my code in an external `test.js` file:

```
$(function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    fabric.Image.fromURL('1.png', function(img) {
      var group = new fabric.Group([img],
        {
          hasBorders: false,
          hasControls: false,
          selectable: true,
          evented: true
        })
      canvas.add(group).setActiveObject(group);
    },
    {
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top'
    });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

And here is the `test.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something? Thank you.

**UPDATE**: solved by using the newest fabricjs (1.3.12) in github.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to disable the objects?

Comment: @Kienz I wish I can move and rescale and rotate my object (which is a group here) as in the demo.

Comment: What exactly you need ? Do you want to hide the object while moving ?

Comment: Just tried your exact code locally — works for me. One of the reasons I can think of is that you have touchpad attached to your computer and you're using Chrome (this was taken care of in later Fabric builds).

Comment: @John I simply want to move my object as in the demo. But I couldn't.

Comment: @kangax Thanks for your information. I finally solved it by disabling the "Enable touch events" flag in Chrome 32.0.1700.19 (Official Build 235778) beta-m Aura. Does it only happen in local development?

Comment: @ziyuang I already fixed it; it should work if you try latest build (1.3.12)